# Solving two coupled 2nd order differential equations with 5 boundary values

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-condition-at-infinity

Suppose I have two 2nd order differential equations:

```
X''[r]+2X'[r]/r = 2(V[r]-u)X[r]
V''[r]+2V'[r]/r = X[r]^2
```

with boundary values

```
X[0]=1
X'[0]=1
V'[0]=0
X'[R]=-SQRT[-2 u]X[R]
V'[R]=-V[R]/r
```

where `R` is a big number but not infinity to avoid difficulties for numerical solving.

How can I solve this kind of equations where `u` is unknown quantity, there is one extra constraint than the number of variables. One should get a system of solutions $(y_i,u_i)$ where $y_i=(X',X'',V',V'')$. I also want to get a plot of `X[r]` vs `r` for `r` from 0 to 15.

Comment: What have you tried thus far? Did you try `NDSolve[]` and somehow it failed? Please share your code.

Comment: NDSolve gives error `NDSolve::ndnco: The number of constraints (5) (initial conditions) is not equal to the total differential order of the system plus the number of discrete variables (4).`  V 14 . Code below if you want to try it....

Comment: `ode1 = X''[r] + 2*X'[r]/r == 2*(V[r] - u)*X[r];
ode2 = V''[r] + 2*V'[r]/r == X[r]^2;
R = 100;
u = 1;
bc = {X[0] == 1, X'[0] == 1, V'[0] == 0, X'[R] == -Sqrt[-2*u]*X[R], 
   V'[R] == -V[R]/r}; NDSolve[{ode1, ode2, bc}, {X, V}, {r, 0, 1}]`

Answer (score 2):

There is singularity at $r\rightarrow 0$, and it is not clear how we can compute `V[R], X[R]` at `R=100` while $0\le r\le 15$. To avoid these troubles, we can supposed that $R=10$ and $r0\le r\le R$, where `r0=10^-6`. In this case we have defined function

```
XV[u_, v_] := 
 Module[{r0 = 10^-6, R = 10}, 
  eq = NDSolveValue[{X''[r] + 2*X'[r]/r == 2*(V[r] - u)*X[r], 
     V''[r] + 2*V'[r]/r == X[r]^2, X[r0] == 1, X'[r0] == 1, 
     V'[r0] == 0, V[r0] == v}, {X'[R] + Sqrt[-2*u]*X[R], 
     V'[R] + V[R]/R}, {r, r0, R}]; eq]
```

Using this function we compute `u,v` as

```
Off[NDSolveValue::ndinnt]
s = FindRoot[XV[u, v] == {0, 0}, {{u, -.47}, {v, -1.14}}]
{u -> -0.692229 + 4.17685*10^-12 I, v -> -1.34176 + 4.17766*10^-12 I}
```

Note, that starting values in `FindRoot` have been computed at `R=2.68`.
Visualization

```
sol2 = NDSolve[{ode1, ode2, bc} /. Chop[s], {X, V}, {r, r0, 10}];

Plot[Evaluate[{X[r], V[r]} /. sol2], {r, r0, 10}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"X", "V"}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Where did you get the initial guess value for u =-.47 and v=-1.14?

Comment: These values coming from preliminary research with `ParametricNDSolve`, where stiffness  detected first at `R=2.65`. So, try to use function `XV` with `R=2.65` and compute roots with initial guess  `{{u, -1}, {v, -1.}}`, then you will get  `{u -> -0.471338, v -> -1.14255}`.